# Using the squeeze theorem liberally to prove a limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

The question is, find the limit of $\ a_n = (e^n+3^n)/5^n$ as $\ n→∞ $
I tried using L'hopital's rule, but didn't seem to get anything useful, so I figured I may be able to use the squeeze theorem. Would this be an appropriate use of the squeeze theorem, and would there be a better method to proving that the limit approaches zero?

$\ 1/n ≤ (e^n+3^n)/5^n ≤ 10/n $ for all n, with both $\ 1/n $ and $\ 10/n $ approaching zero as n approaches infinity.

Comment: Yes, that is fine, if you can actually prove the two bounds.

Comment: Do you know the property, given $a \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $|a| < 1$, then $\lim a^n = 0$?

Comment: Ok, that property combined with the answers given, prove that the limity approaches zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** I don't believe the bounds you have are correct. Instead, I suggest something like $$0\leq\frac{e^n+3^n}{5^n}\leq\frac{3^n+3^n}{5^n}=2\cdot\frac{3^n}{5^n}.$$ These inequalities are much more obvious, hold for all $n$, thus we can take the limit. What do we get?

Answer (score 3):

It might be easiest to think of it as
$\displaystyle a_n = \Big(\frac{e}{5}\Big)^n + \Big(\frac35\Big)^n $.